# Bootstrap navbar items wont line up properly

Tags: bootstrap-4

Hi i am having trouble fixing my nav bar so that it is even and so that an item doesnt take too much space

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary fixed-top text-uppercase" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">My Name</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Menu
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
          <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Over mij</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
          <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Persoonlijke ontwikkeling</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
          <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Curriculum vitae</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
          <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
          <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="indexEN.html">English</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and how it looks now : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHIAQ.jpg
and how it should look: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/
,any help is very welcome!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to adjust it according to your needs. I removed padding. It is now working as you expected.

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary fixed-top text-uppercase" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">My Name</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Menu
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Over mij</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Persoonlijke ontwikkeling</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Curriculum vitae</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="indexEN.html">English</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Or use the `px-0` class

Comment: Thanks it fixed a part of the problem. https://imgur.com/a/cHeljGN , still have the problem with the Nav being on top not hover mode, wich is this https://imgur.com/a/wmM5hWU il try to work around it with what you gave me. but why doesnt it apply to both instances ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/msMtZug I find it rather annoying that this one itemlist has to have no padding otherwise it causes problems to the whole navbar....If u have any ideas on how to work around it let me know please.For the most part problem is fixed.

Comment: Ok no need anymore i think, i somehow fixed it by just sacrificing some pixels everywhere to make it even on every itemlist!